# javascript - load data into array of array

Tags: javascript

I am slowly building my javascript code to eventually load some data from a json file.  I am using an embedded table tabella.js.  At this time i just want to load some test data in the table header through a loop

this is the demo set up:

```
var dataTest = {};

    dataTest.tableHeader = [
      ["6534", "6756"],
      ["7000", "7100"],
      ["7200", "7300"],
      ["7400", "7500"],
      ["7600", "7700"],
      ["7800", "7900"],
      ["8000", "8100"],
      ["8200", "8300"],
      ["8400", "8400"]
   ]
```

I would like to load through a loop some data to replace the demo data, but i have dataTest.tableHeader undefined error so here my version:

```
var dataTest = {};
      var i;

    for (i=0; i<9; i++){
         dataTest.tableHeader[i]=["0","1"];
    }

    //dataTest.tableHeader = [
     // ["6534", "6756"],
     // ["7000", "7100"],
     // ["7200", "7300"],
     // ["7400", "7500"],
     // ["7600", "7700"],
     // ["7800", "7900"],
     // ["8000", "8100"],
    //  ["8200", "8300"],
    //  ["8400", "8400"]
```

//    ]

```
        console.log(dataTest.tableHeader[2])
```

what is wrong?

Comment: You're creating a new empty `dataTest` variable at the top of your second snippet, so it has no `tableHeader` property - there's no array to assign to or to push to. Your code will not even run, it will throw an error before it gets to `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the tableHeader property first.

```
var dataTest = {};
dataTest.tableHeader = [];
var i;
for (i=0; i<9; i++){
     dataTest.tableHeader[i]=["0","1"];
}
```